# Secure copying files from a remote server to local machine from a list in a text file

Tags: scp, cat, xargs

I have about a thousand files on a remote server (all in different directories). I would like to scp them to my local machine. I would not want to run scp command a thousand times in a row, so I have created a text file with a list of file locations on the remote server. It is a simple text file with a path on each line like below:

...

```
/iscsi/archive/aat/2005/20050801/A/RUN0010.FTS
/iscsi/archive/aat/2006/20060201/A/RUN0062.FTS
/iscsi/archive/aat/2013/20130923/B/RUN0010.FTS
/iscsi/archive/aat/2009/20090709/A/RUN1500.FTS
```

...

I have searched and found someone trying to do a similar but not the same thing [here](https://superuser.com/questions/851416/using-scp-to-transfer-a-txt-file-list-of-files). The command I would like to edit is below:

```
cat /location/file.txt | xargs -i scp {} user@server:/location
```

In my case I need something like:

```
cat fileList.txt | xargs -i scp user@server:{} .
```

To download files from a remote server using the list in fileList.txt located in the same directory I run this command from.

When I run this I get an error: xargs: illegal option -- i

How can I get this command to work?

Thanks,
Aina.

Comment: Use `rsync`. It will be much faster and less pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error `xargs: illegal option -- i` because `-i` was deprecated. Use `-I {}` instead (you could also use a different replace string but `{}` is fine).

If the list is remote, the files are remote, you can do this to retrieve it locally and use it with `xargs -I {}`:

```
ssh user@server cat fileList.txt | xargs -I {} scp user@server:{} .
```

But this creates N+1 connections, and more importantly this copies all remote files (scattered in different directories you said) to the same local directory. Probably not what you want.

So, in order to recreate a similar hierarchy locally, let's say everything under `/iscsi/archive/aat`, you can:

- use `cut -d/` to extract the part you want to be identical on both sides
- use a subshell to create the command that creates the target directory and copies the file there

Thus:

```
ssh user@server cat fileList.txt \
| cut -d/ -f4- \
| xargs -I {} sh -c 'mkdir -p $(dirname {}); scp user@server:/iscsi/archive/{} ./{}'
```

Should work, but that's starting to look messy, and you still have N+1 connections, so now `rsync` looks like a better option. If you have passwordless ssh connection, this should work:

```
rsync -a --files-from=<(ssh user@server cat fileList.txt) user@server:/ .
```

The leading `/` is stripped by rsync and in the end you'll get everything under `./iscsi/archive/...`.

You can also copy the files locally first, and then:

```
rsync -a --files-from=localCopyOfFileList.txt user@server:/ .
```

You can also manipulate that file to remove for example 2 levels:

```
rsync -a --files-from=localCopyOfFileList2.txt user@server:/iscsi/archive .
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks, Hugues, this is EXACTLY what I wanted! Indeed I have a file list locally and having all the files in the same directory locally is not ideal, so `rsync -a --files-from=localCopyOfFileList.txt user@server:/ .`has done a perfect job for what I want to do! Thanks for your help!